# How to quote scripts to make single quotation not gone away?

Tags: python

I'd like to add some words in a file using python script. Here is my script(for which name is `test.py`) and how I excute the script.

```
import os
some_python_words = "sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))\n"
scripts = "echo '%s' >> 'conf.py' " % (some_python_words)
os.system(scripts)
```

As I am execute in the terminal by `python test.py`. What writes in my file is

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(..))
```

The single quotation `''` of `..` is gone. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the handling of single- and double-qoutes in the shell. A single-quoted string can't have interior single-quotes, but a double-quote can. See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for a great writeup.

Just change your quoting when creating the shell string

```
scripts = """echo "%s" >> 'conf.py' """ % (some_python_words)
```